# Forward *.Company.com to an IP address

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to forward all *.company.com URLs to my company.com IP address. Is this possible with Godaddy DNS? The reason I want this is so that I can deliver different logos based on the company using my application (eg. ibm.company.com, bell.company.com etc. will see a respective IBM and Bell logo at the top). I need the prefix so that my application will remain branded even without a user session on the system, such as on the logon, registration and password recovery screen. So I am also open to a criticism of this idea for as a branding solution, and a discussion of a better solution... [using ASP.NET]

Comment: Move to ServerFault?

Comment: Its certainly nothing to do with html or css... might be possible with c# / .net though but not that I know of...

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: Shouldn't be - .net wouldn't get any request if the dns isn't pointing in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a cname record in the total dns settings

**Host**
use * 
**Points to**
company.com IP address

Then just check the host with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

http://scottelkin.com/programming/how-to-properly-configure-godaddy-dns-settings/